# How to modify this `printf` code to reverse it's action?

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting, printf, ed

Code below can, for example ...

```
[anony@mous-pc ~]$ (printf 'g?%s?m0\n' 008 006 004 002 ; printf 'wq\n') | ed -s file.txt
```

... take all of numbers within ...

```
[anony@mous-pc ~]$ cat some.txt
005
003
110
069
002
008
004
245
009
007
006
```

... and move desired numbers wanted moved (or any other strings) to top in exact order given in code executed, like so:

```
[anony@mous-pc ~]$ cat some.txt
002
004
006
008
005
003
110
069
245
009
007
```

---

How can this code be reversed to make these numbers order at the bottom of the .txt rather than at the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `0` in the `ed` script to `$`.  The `$` addresses the last line of the editing buffer.

```
$ { printf 'g?%s?m$\n' 008 006 004 002; echo 'wq'; } | ed -s file.txt
$ cat file.txt
005
003
110
069
245
009
007
008
006
004
002
```

Would you want them in reverse order (the order you had in the question), you would have to reverse the list of patterns.

```
$ { printf 'g?%s?m$\n' 002 004 006 008; echo 'wq'; } | ed -s file.txt
$ cat file.txt
005
003
110
069
245
009
007
002
004
006
008
```

Or, for that matter,

```
{ printf 'g?%s?m$\n' 008 006 004 002 | tac; echo 'wq'; } | ed -s file.txt
```

... if you have `tac` from GNU coreutils installed.  On some systems (BSD) you may use `tail -r` in place of `tac`.

Comment: ... and you can use ( ) or { } ?

Comment: @AnonymousUser `( ... )` executes a sub-shell. If I only want to group a set of commands for the purpose of redirecting their output to the same place, I tend to use `{ ...; }`, which is faster. It doesn't _really_ matter here.

Comment: So you mean you wouldn't have to cd to the directory in the script? It would just know where things are?

Comment: You said `0` is the only thing that needs to be changed to a `$` to make the code work in reverse, but I noticed you piped the original `printf` options (please correct me on the proper word here, if not options) to `tac`. And then `echo` `wq` rather than using `printf` again which is already in the code. But why? Wouldn't keeping `printf` going make things simpler in more ways than one? It's not even less characters. So why, exactly?

Comment: @AnonymousUser Changing the `0` to `$` is the only thing that is needed to move lines to the end rather than to the top. I use `echo` for outputting strings that are not variable, such as `wq`. You may still use `printf` to do this. I used `tac` to reverse the command outputted by `printf` as an alternative to specifying the numbers in the opposite order. It's not clear by what you mean by "reverse", and whether this included reversing the order of the lines.

Comment: Why do you recommend to use the non-standard `tac` when there is the standard `tail -r`?

Comment: @schily No reason other than that I did not know about it. I'll amend my answer accordingly. On second thought, if it's standard, it ought to be mentioned by POSIX, which it isn't.  It seems to be a BSD thing.

Comment: Well, there is a small problem: GNU tools do not support `tail -r` but on a typical UNIX, `tail` supports the `-r` option since ~ 40 years. `tail -r` is required to be supported by the OpenGroup base specification issue 8 - the requirement has been added nearly 5 years ago. So on nearly all systems, `tail -r` works. The problem only exists on GNU based systems.

Comment: @schily Not mentioned here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html

Comment: This is issue 7 ;-), I am talking about issue 8.... see http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=877

Comment: @schily Not published yet?

Comment: We make a new version (probably called issue 7 tc3) for IEEE to the end of this year and next year, the main work for issue 8 begins. On the other side, it is always wise to keep an eye on the "bug fixes", since there have been unfortunate text problems that have been fixed in austinbugs and people could believe they implemented their code correctly. See e.g. the buggy `waitid()` on Linux, that is based on a textual bug in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Store lines in separate containers depending on whether they need to move south or remain in place. Then when all lines have been looked at this way, print them in the desired order.

```
$ perl -ne 'push @{/_00[2468]$/ ? \@A : \@B}, $_}{print @B, @A' input.txt
```

You can do this with posix sed also:

```
$ sed -ne '
    /_00[2468]$/s//&/w data2468
    //!p
    $r data2468
' input.txt
```